# Create a variable from a Remote Ping Response IP Address

Tags: powershell

I need to be able to ping a range of IP addresses and when I get a reply on one, then capture that IP to put in a variable which I can use to update the local computers host file.

The purpose of this script is to be used for a Point-to-Site Azure VPN service. A remote server is connecting as a client and is given a second IP address which changes on each connection. The other server can only communicate to the remote server on this IP address, but the application it uses only uses DNS Names, so I will need to update the hosts file with the connecting servers IP each time it dials in.

```
$subnet = "172.16.201.0"
$start = 1
$end = 10
$ping = 1
while ($start -le $end) {
$IP = "172.16.201.$start"
Write-Host "Pinging $IP" -ForegroundColor Cyan
Test-Connection -ComputerName $IP -count 1 -Quiet
$start++
}
```

So far the above code only does a IP Sweep and outputs the success/failure of each IP. I need to capture the success IP and put that in a variable

Comment: do you want to stop the sweep when you get a valid IP?

Comment: Yes that would work, there will only be one active IP during the sweep. I couldn't limit the VPN DHCP Pool to anything lower then ten and assigning static IPs to connecting clients isn't supporting by Azure

Comment: kool! that is what i went with ... please let me know if the answer i posted does the job. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

i presume you want only the 1st responding IP address, not all the addresses in the range. [*grin*] you can turn this into a function fairly easily. you can also turn OFF the verbose output by commenting out the 2nd line.

```
$Old_VPref = $VerbosePreference
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

$Subnet = '192.168.1'
$RangeStart = 60
$RangeEnd = 69

$1stRespondingIPv4 = foreach ($Octet in $RangeStart..$RangeEnd)
    {
    $IP = $Subnet, $Octet -join '.'
    $WV_Msg = 'Testing {0} ...' -f $IP
    Write-Verbose -Message $WV_Msg
    $Pingable = Test-Connection -ComputerName $IP -Count 1 -Quiet

    if ($Pingable)
        {
        $IP
        # the next line stops the foreach loop
        break
        }
    }

''
$1stRespondingIPv4

$VerbosePreference = $Old_VPref
```

output ...

```
VERBOSE: Testing 192.168.1.60 ...
VERBOSE: Testing 192.168.1.61 ...
VERBOSE: Testing 192.168.1.62 ...
VERBOSE: Testing 192.168.1.63 ...
VERBOSE: Testing 192.168.1.64 ...

192.168.1.64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dns = "domain.com"
$ipAddresses = @(
    "172.16.201.0"
    "172.16.201.1"
    "172.16.201.2"
    "172.16.201.3"
    "172.16.201.4"
    "172.16.201.5"
    "172.16.201.6"
    "172.16.201.7"
    "172.16.201.8"
    "172.16.201.9"
    "172.16.201.10"
)
foreach($ip in $ipAddresses) {
    Write-Host "Pinging $ip" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $ping = Test-Connection -ComputerName "$ip" -count 1 -Quiet
    if ($ping) {
        Add-Content -Path "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" -Value "$ip     $dns"
        Write-Host "The host file was updated with the successful IP and hostname: $ip    $dns" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    }

}
```